# Best Index For Partitioned Table

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, partitioning

I am querying a fairly large table that has been range partitioned (by someone else) by date into one partition per day. On average there are about 250,000 records per day. Frequently queries will be by a range of days -- usually looking for one day, 7 day week or a calendar month. Right now querying for more than 2 weeks is not performing well--have a normal date index created. If I query for more than 5 days it doesn't use the index, if I use an index hint it performs o.k. from about 5 days to 14 days but beyond that the index hint doesn't help much.

Given that the hint does better than the optimizer I am doing a gather statistics on the table.

However, my question going forward is, in general, if I wanted to create an index on the date field in the table, is it best to create a range partitioned index? Is it best to create a range index with a daily range similar to the table partition? What would be the best strategy?

This is Oracle 11g.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

related to your question, partitioning strategy will depend on how you are going to query the data, the best strategy would be to query as fewer partitions as possible. e.g. if you are going to run monthly reports you'd rather  create montly range partitioning and not daily range partitioning. If all your queryies will be around data that's within a couple of days then daily range partitioning would be fine.

Given numbers you provided in my opininon you overpartition data.

p.s. quering each partition requires additional reading(than if it were just one partition), so optimizer opts for table access full to reduce reading of indexes.

Comment: Using the index hint the cost is 5 times higher than not using it, but using the index hint the query runs 20 times faster. Is this normal?

Comment: it's normal as I said when you use partitions you cause additional readings because the index structure is different to the structure where you do not have partitions. When you query only few partitions oracle will use partition pruning and you are fine. you have to go to documentation and read what's the difference between global and local indexes, if you swap/drop/..(these actions invalidate global indexes) partitions rarely you can re-create your index as a global index it should help for querieng data

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a global index on date column. If the index is partitioned and you select -let's say- 14 days, then Oracle has to read 14 indexes. Having a single index on the entire table, i.e. "global index" it has to read only 1 index.

Note, when you truncate or drop a partition then you have to rebuild the index afterwards.

Comment: I originally created the index without any options--so by default that is a global non-partitioned index, correct?

Comment: this is what I meant in my post, after adding comment about global index I've read your post

Answer (score 0):

I'm *guessing* that you could be writing your SQL wrong.

You said you're querying by date. If your date column has time part and you want to extract records from one day, from specific time of the day, e.g. 20:00-21:00, then yes, an index would be beneficial and I would recommend a local index for this (partitioned by day as just like table).

But since your queries span a range of days, it seems this is not the case and you just want all data (maybe filtered by some other attributes). If so, a **partition full scan** will always be much faster than index access... provided you benefit from partition pruning! Because if not - and you're actually performing a **full table scan** - this is expected to be very, very slow (in most cases).

So what could go wrong? Are you using plain date in WHERE clause? Note that:

```
SELECT * FROM trx WHERE trx_date = to_date('2014-04-03', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

will scan only one partition, whereas:

```
SELECT * FROM trx WHERE trunc(trx_date) = to_date('2014-04-03', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

will scan all partitions, as you apply a function to partitioning key and the optimizer can no longer determine which partitions to scan.

It would be much easier to tell for sure if you provided table definition, total number of partitions, sample data and your queries with explain plans. If possible, please edit your question and include more details.